# Neural network without test

Tags: neural-networks, overfitting

Is wrong to perform neural network using all the data as training (excluding so the test)?
I'm obtaining really different results including or not the test. Is possible that I'm encountering and overfitting?

Answer (score 1):

The typical way is to spit the data set into training, validation, and test set.

This allows you to detect overfitting and perform early stop. E.g.:

[image]

Comment: I know it, but I want to compare results of different evaluation models using the same dataset. Because of this would be better to use all the data as training but I guess this produce overfitting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a smaller proportion of your dataset as test dataset, but you should know that it may not be enough to judge if this model can predict new data. 
What do you mean very different results? Tested on what data?
When you use all data as your training set, it is normal for the model to be able to predict them, while it may not predict future data.
So, yes, your model is probably overfitting in this case.

Comment: Thanks Cipher! My database is composed by ~400 units, one dependent variable (that's a quality judgment) and 18 independent variables (characteristics of the product) all ordinal. I mean results are different if i reduce the dataset to include the test or if i don't. In the first case (80% training and 20% test) I obtain 70% of correct classification for the training and 60% for the test. Running the model without test (100% training) the correct results are 80%.

Comment: Dario, what I try to say above is that for the case you are using 100% of your data for training, the results (80%) are on the training data? If so, this is not accurate at all, and you can not know if what you get if overfitting. If you believe that you need more data, I would suggest data augmentation or using the minimum possible data for testing (but definitely above 0%  :)

Comment: Yes, 80% of correct predictions is the result applying 100% of the data as training data. Is there a minimum percentage of test that should be used (like 5-10%)? By the way, if I understand is "wrong" use all the data for the training. As I said to Frank my problem is that I'm going to compare the prediction results with other models, so it would be better to use the same data for prediction, but I guess I can't...

Comment: Common practice is to separate the whole dataset by 70-30 (training-testing). But this is not something standard. It depends on how certain you want to be of the efficiency of the model. I suggest trying 90-10 with [k-fold validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) or augmenting the dataset if possible. And please note again that 80% percent probably means that the model could not describe the training set, so you should probably not expect better results on any test set. Try increasing the capacity of your model (parameters) or raise the number of the epochs.